# Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space give an example of two closed (nonempty) sets $A$ and $B$ with $A \cap B=\emptyset $ and such that $d(A,B)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Define the distance between two nonempty subsets $A$ and $B$ of $X$ by
$$d(A,B)=\inf\{d(x,y):x\in A\quad and \quad y\in B\}$$
(a) Give an example of two closed sets $A$ and $B$ with $A \cap B=\emptyset$ and such that $d(A,B)=0.$

(b) If $A \cap B = \emptyset,A$ is clossed and $B$ is closed and bounded (both nonempty) then show that $d(A,B)>0.$

So for the first part I thought if I chose the metric space $\mathbb{R}$ and let $A=\{0\}$ and $B=\{y\in \mathbb{R}:1\le y\le10\}$

These are two subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and the are closed and their intersection is empty.And if I understand the distance formula correctly it is the glb of any interval $d(x,y)$ and in my case any interval $d(0,y)$

But then if this is true I do not really understand what I am supposed to be accomplishing in part (b)

I would appreciate a nudge in the right direction, and confirmation at my attempt of part (a)

Comment: For (a), you could choose, in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $A:=\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$ and $B$ to be the graph of $x\mapsto e^x$.

Comment: Your attempt for (a) is incorrect. You get $d(A,B)=d(0,1)=1$.

Comment: @B ry You should think of $d(A,B)$ as the distance between the nearest points of $A$ and $B$.  But since these could be infinite sets, there may not be a single pair of points that achieves a minimum, so it's defined as an infimum instead.  In your example it's obvious from graphing the two sets that the distance is $1$, not $0$.

Comment: @Eric Wong See i wasn't sure if I could assume the distance d(x,y) was the actual distance between the points of A and the points of B i thought it was just creating and interval of numbers that we then determine its greatest lower bound. That why i chose the singleton {0} cause any set would have the GLB of 0. Which is essentially what the inf would be on these bounded subsets.

Comment: @B ry The distance from $0$ to any point in $B$ is always $\ge 1$.  Sure, $0$ is a lower bound for the distance but $1$ is a *greater* lower bound.

Comment: @Eric Wong Okay so just to clarify when they say d(x,y) and they don't specify what that means then I can just assume its the distance between any arbitrary x and y (and calculate this way |x-y|) in our subsets? Or is this only true in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @B ry What do you mean?  They already specified what $d(x,y)$ means in the very first sentence: $(X,d)$ is a metric space.

Comment: @Eric Wong how do you know that d(x,y) say for x=0 and y=1 will evaluate to 1? What is it in the question that grants us that knowledge

Comment: @B ry You said yourself that you are *choosing* $X$ to be the metric space $\mathbb R$.  If you aren't using the standard metric on $\mathbb R$ then you haven't actually chosen a metric space at all (and if you change the metric you need to reconsider whether your sets are still closed in that metric — this is the key advantage of using an existing metric space to build examples on).

Comment: Got it, I just wanted to make sure i was able to assume the standard distance functions for $\mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The graph of $1/x$ and the $x$-axis are both closed subsets of $\mathbb R^2$, and they are disjoint, but their distance is still $0$: no matter how tiny $\epsilon >0$ is you can still find two points, one from each set, that are closer than $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

Take $X=R$, $A=N-\{0\}$, $B=\{n+1/n, n>0, n\in N\}$

Comment: In this case could B still be closed?

Comment: @B ry This example is a discrete set, hence closed.  Every pair of points is at least $1/2$ apart.

Comment: because as $n\to \infty $ wouldn't the endpoints be $[2,\infty)$ and therefore not contain its limit points or at each value of n could we close it with brackets and thus conclude that it contains its endpoints?

Comment: @B ry There are no endpoints in $B$.  It is a collection of isolated points.  Please read the notation carefully.